# How to get a list of pending users for a particular group in Yammer

Tags: c#, yammer

I 'm trying to get a list of pending members from a specific group in Yammer, here is the code Itried

```
string accessToken = "575-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string GetPendingRequestapiUrl = "www.yammer.com/groupName/groupId/get_members?_=1501062735925.json";
HttpWebRequest yammerRequest = WebRequest.Create(GetPendingRequestapiUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
yammerRequest.Method = "GET";
yammerRequest.Host = "www.yammer.com";
yammerRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8; odata=verbose";
yammerRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + accessToken);
using (HttpWebResponse resp = yammerRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
Encoding e = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), e);
jsondata = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
}
```

Error received :"The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable."

I know there is no documented api for this however there are several undocumented apis which are working so could you please me with this api or any other workaround to get the pending members list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with the support team, they have confirmed that there is no public api to get pending users from a particular group.